# Concat with NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query which looks something like this:

```
select distinct col1,
(
    select ltrim(str(col2))+','
    from @temp t2
    where t2.col1 = t1.col1
    for xml path('')
) col2
from @temp t1
```

Some of the values in col2 are null, so instead of displaying a string with null, that part is missing totally, i.e.

col2 should have

```
3,4,3,NULL,2,3,4,3,2,
```

but instead I am getting:

```
3,4,3,2,3,4,3,2,
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: Can you post an executable repro? Replace the subquery with constant NULL for testing purposes.

Comment: @usr, Unfortunately, executable repro is new to me.  Don't know what that means.

Comment: Post a query that anyone can execute to see the wrong results.

Comment: @oshirowanen: For your convenience I posted a sample reproduction statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a NULL output, you'll need to change the NULL value into the string 'NULL'. That also means that you'll need to cast the numeric value to a string to have a consistent type for the field;

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1,
(
    SELECT COALESCE(CAST(col2 AS VARCHAR),'NULL')+','
    FROM @temp t2
    WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1
    FOR XML PATH('')
) col2
FROM @temp t1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20489).

Answer (score 1):

A NULL value is not the string NULL. It is simply absence of information. What you could do is to force a NULL value to be treated as the string NULL for your purposes like so:

```
SELECT CASE
      WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
      ELSE col2
      END + ','
```

To make it more concise, you may use `isnull(col2,'NULL')` or `coalesce(col2,'NULL')`

If `col2` is not a text type, cast it first before using any of the above solutions like so:

```
SELECT CASE
      WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
      ELSE CAST(col2 AS VARCHAR(5))
      END + ','
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT col1,
        (
           SELECT ISNULL(CAST(col2 AS VARCHAR(10)),'NULL') + ','
           FROM   @Temp AS T2
           WHERE  T2.col1 = T1.col1
           FOR    XML PATH('')
        ) AS col2
FROM    @Temp AS T1
```

Add any value to NULL will result **NULL**

> *ANY VALUE + NULL* = **NULL**

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Hope it was helpful

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (col1 INT,col2 INT)

INSERT INTO @temp (col1,col2)
VALUES (1, 2),
      (1, 3),
      (1, 4),
      (1, NULL),
      (1, 6),
      (1, 7)

SELECT DISTINCT col1,
             SUBSTRING((
             SELECT ','+LTRIM(ISNULL(STR(col2),'NULL'))
             FROM @temp AS t2
             WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1
             FOR XML PATH('')
             ),2,200000) AS col2
FROM @temp AS t1
```